# Permission Denied when trying to download a torrent?

Tags: filesystem, permissions, transmission

[image]

I want to know the solution to this and resume my downloading.
I am running Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: you may use gimp to "gully" unwanted text away :)

Comment: @BRoland: There. Fixed.

Comment: Didnt know about that. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my system: `drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 2011-02-13 13:36 media/` it is writeable only by root. The system stores here the mounted volumes, like: USB flash drive, Cardreader, mounted HDDs... etc...

If you are looking for a place, where you want to store your personal data, in only your home dir, like: `/home/YourName` or the siple `~` refers to it.

Ubuntu makes you some default dirs, like: Music, Video... in your home dir. I suggest you, to place your movies there, to Videos; or you can individualy make a dir in your home folder. This is situated on **GNOME menu > Places > Home folder** (the first)

Illustration(from google):
[image: home dir ubuntu 10.10]

Comment: /media is usually a space where other filesystems are mounted, but a directory is created in that, and that directory's ownership is set, etc etc. So it's useless to check the permissions of /media, because especially removable medias are automounted in a directory created in /media with proper permissions.

Comment: `The system stores here the mounted volumes, like: USB flash drive, Cardreader, mounted HDDs... etc...`
I wrote that, "etc" means the others, what hasn't listed. I checked the permissons only to make my suggestions understood.

Comment: Roland: I see, and you'right, but I haven't understood why you mentioned the permission of /media itself, it's totally unimportant since it's not a habit to have one filesystem mounted right in /media, but one directory deeper only. Also from the screenshot (what the question has) I have the idea that some media is mounted there which has the name "The.Green.Hornet....", that's why I've suggested in my answer to check out what it is.

Comment: Thanks will change all download locations to a dir in home folder!

Answer (score 0):

It seems transmission can't open the target file, maybe you don't have the proper rights for that. What's mounted in that directory /media/The.Green. ... ? Use terminal, this command: `df -aT /media/...` where the path at the end is the same as your screenshot shows.

Why do you want to download there? Do you have some pendrive, whatever which is autmounted and you want to download onto it? I am just wondering why don't you download into your home directory, have you got any special reason?

Comment: I am downloading it in a external HDD. Its a 1TB WD MyBook. I have everything saved on that drives. My folders, documents, music, videos. Everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store user files in the `/media` folder, it contains mount points for removable media like CD's or USB memory sticks. This folder is owned by the root user who has permission to write to this directory (owner=root, group=root, mode=0755).

Each user has a Home folder, located at `/home/you-username`. In that directory, you can store your personal files and settings. Ubuntu creates additional directories in that folder like `Videos`, in which you can put your downloaded videos.

Please read the manual page about the [Filesystem hierarchy](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man7/hier.7.html) to get a better understanding of folders like `/media`.

Answer (score 0):

Transmission does not run under the logged-in username, instead it uses the username 'debian-transmission'. Consequently, downloading to a home folder won't work, because 'debian-transmission' does not have write permissions to any of the user's home folders. The default download location is in the /var directory, because 'debian-transmission' (and I believe most local users?) have write access to that directory tree.

mikewhatever answers the question of how to download directly into one of the /home folders, in this other askubuntu: [Permission denied when downloading with transmission deamon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221081/permission-denied-when-downloading-with-transmission-deamon)