# Permissions problem downloading to a folder NOT on the boot drive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, qbittorrent

I have a problem similar to [Permission denied when downloading with transmission deamon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26125/permission-denied-when-trying-to-download-a-torrent), but I see nothing there that would help me resolve things.

My (X86 / 64bit) Ubuntu 16.04 system runs from a 64Gb (msata) SSD, on one of these brilliant [fanless mini-desktop machines](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Eggsnow-Aluminum-Fanless-Desktop-Computer/dp/B078T7B3N7), to which I added an internal 500Gb sata drive.

According to one of the answers to that earlier question, [You should not store user files in the /media folder](https://askubuntu.com/a/26191/222837). But I didn't get any choice about the fact that Ubuntu identifies my sata drive as **/media/username/3AE67CF2E67CAFAD** (search me where it got that hex string from; I'd rather have something a bit more meaningful!).

---

In a  nutshell, my problem is that I want qBittorrent to download onto the higher-capacity drive. I don't care if *by default* other apps carry on using the /Download folder on the SSD - I just want control of the qBittorrent output location. But so far all I get is permission errors (access denied) when QBittorrent tries to write to the designated folder (.../3AE67CF2E67CAFAD/download2) on the drive I'm trying to use.

I'm not exactly well-versed in Ubuntu/Linux, so if there's a *really easy* way to resolve things, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: The hex string indicates that you have the NTFS file system in the partition. Is that correct? Otherwise, please tell us about the file system. The reason is that the permissions and ownership of all files and directories in Microsoft file systems are set when mounting in linux, while linux file systems can be controlled in a detailed way with individual permissions and ownership. See this link for more details, https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072?s=4|14.2986#956072

Comment: @sudodus: Ah, right! I think that's gonna be it! (The 500Gb drive came from a Win10 system.) The answer in your link looks intimidatingly complicated to me, so I'd be worried about screwing it up and losing the couple hundred Gb of media files already on the drive. I have a large USB drive I can temporarily copy them to. It'll take *ages* - but at least I can just leave the machine to get on with that overnight, then tomorrow I can reformat the drive under Ubuntu and with any luck it'll all start working the way I want it to. I'll leave the question open until then though, if that's okay here.

Comment: It is a good idea to backup the content of your drive before you go ahead and modify the drive. Good luck :-)